# How to define a Python class to inherit all other modules function?

Tags: python

I wrote several modules to operate a system for different stuff. Only need the IP address of the system.
Now, is it possile to define a class to inherit all functions already developed in other python modules? Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can `extend` classes from other modules:

```
import other_module

class MyClass(other_module.OtherClass):
    def my_function(self):
        #do something that calls a function that belonged to OtherClass
        self.other_function()
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to list all callable functions in other 12 modules, and find a way to call those function from a class.

Comment: some other module do not have class inside.

Comment: @user1008009: These points would make excellent additions to your questions!